# PHP: Find depth of current array in recursive function

Tags: php

is there any way that I can get current depth of array?
So far, I had no luck with this..

My code:

```
use app\components\TreeView;
use app\models\Kategorije;
$tree = TreeView::getMenu();

function recursion($stablo,&$indent) {
    $indent++; // Try to get depth of current array
    foreach ($stablo as $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
            $indent_str = str_repeat("-", $indent);
            echo $indent.$value['label'].'<br>';
            if (!empty($value['items'])) {
                recursion($value['items'],$indent);
            }
        };
    }
}
$indent = 0;
recursion($tree,$indent);
```

I need that depth for indentation...

Comment: Post your array structure along with expected output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149028/how-to-find-the-depth-of-an-unlimited-depthed-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-deep-a-php-array-is

Comment: Dont use &$indent as a reference => function recursion($stablo,$indent)

Comment: @AlexisPeters Thanks, that solved my problem! :)