# Looping through array of unlimited children and display to a table

Tags: php, arrays, loops, cakephp

I don't have any idea how to loop through this array and display it to an HTML table. Child data are dynamic and can be unlimited. Anyone can give me a clue? Thanks!

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Discount] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [lft] => 1
                    [rght] => 6
                    [name] => Discount 1
                    [value] => 25
                )

            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Discount] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 10
                                    [parent_id] => 8
                                    [lft] => 2
                                    [rght] => 5
                                    [name] => Child of D1
                                    [value] => 32
                                )

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Discount] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 11
                                                    [parent_id] => 10
                                                    [lft] => 3
                                                    [rght] => 4
                                                    [name] => The 1.1.1
                                                    [value] => 65
                                                )

                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I know I can't just do:

```
foreach($discounts as $discount){
    echo "<div>{$discount['Discount']['name']}</div>";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional Arrays Nested to Unlimited Depth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312425/multidimensional-arrays-nested-to-unlimited-depth)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($Discount as $children => $value) {
     echo "<div>{$discount['Discount']['$children']['name']}</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need recursion to properly generate the HTML. Here is an example that I hope is helpful. This isn't exactly HOW you'll want to generate the final HTML but this should get you started on the right track:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'discount' => array(
            'id' => 8,
            'parent_id' => 0,
            'lft' => 1,
            'rght' => 6,
            'name' => 'Discount 1',
            'value' => 25,
        ),
        'children' => array(
            0 => array(
                'discount' => array(
                    'id' => 10,
                    'parent_id' => 8,
                    'lft' => 2,
                    'rght' => 5,
                    'name' => 'Child of D1',
                    'value' => 32,
                ),
                'children' => array(
                    0 => array(
                        'discount' => array(
                            'id' => 11,
                            'parent_id' => 10,
                            'lft' => 3,
                            'rght' => 4,
                            'name' => 'The 1.1.1',
                            'value' => 65,
                        ),
                        'children' => array(),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

$html = getHtml($data);

/**
 * This function is called recursively to generate the necessary HTML
 * @param array $data
 */
function getHtml(array $data)
{
    // This is your base conditon to end the recursion. It stops once it hits an empty children array
    if (empty($data)) {
        return;
    }
    $data = $data[0]; // will have to tweak this if you have more than 1 element per array
    $html = sprintf('<div id="%d" name="%s">', $data['discount']['id'], $data['discount']['name']);
    $html .= getHtml($data['children']); // this recursive call generates inner HTML
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}

// See the result
var_dump($html);
```