# Modifying multidimensional array of unknown depth

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, iterator

My problem is very similar to: [Multidimensional Arrays Nested to Unlimited Depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312425/multidimensional-arrays-nested-to-unlimited-depth)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4333381/404623) from the above question works for traversing, however I need to modify the values in the array inside the loop.

```
$depth = 2; // This is actually a method argument passed at runtime

$it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveArrayIterator($arr),
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
$it->setMaxDepth($depth);

// PHP Fatal error:  An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference
foreach ($it as $key => &$value) {
    if ($it->getDepth() === $depth - 1) {
        $value = 'foo';
    }
}

// I also tried this, which gives:
// PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type RecursiveIteratorIterator as array
foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    if ($it->getDepth() === $depth - 1) {
        $it[$key] = 'foo';
    }
}
```

How can I mutate the array while traversing?

Comment: mutate the array how? change the structure that you are trying to traverse? That can get 'interesting'. Or trying to manipulate the data values of the nodes?

Comment: @RyanVincent At the second-deepest level I want to create and remove some nodes